# Zooming and rotating a UITextView

Tags: ios, rotation, uitextview, zooming

I need to zoom and rotate a custom UITextView that I'm already dragging around my UIView. My UITextView has a black border around it.

The problem is that if I zoom the UITextView with a gesture and then rotate my UITextView, the text goes out of bounds and acts weird.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to provide some code in order for anyone to help. Any UIView can be rotated but the problem you'll be dealing with is trying to rotate a UIScrollView and also allow scrolling. You'll need to capture the proper view to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

~~ ZoomRotatePanTextView.h ~~

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ZoomRotatePanTextView : UITextView
- (void) reset:(BOOL)animation;
@end
```

~~ ZoomRotatePanTextView.m ~~

```
#import "ZoomRotatePanTextView.h"

@interface ZoomRotatePanTextView () <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecogniser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotateRecogniser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecogniser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecogniser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecogniser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecogniser;

- (void) setUpGestures;
- (IBAction) handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)recogniser;
- (IBAction) handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)recogniser;
- (IBAction) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recogniser;
- (IBAction) handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recogniser;
- (IBAction) handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recogniser;
- (IBAction) handleLongPress:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recogniser;
@end

@implementation ZoomRotatePanTextView

#pragma mark - Initialisation Overrides

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setUpGestures];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setUpGestures];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setUpGestures];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setUpGestures {
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    _pinchRecogniser = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
    _rotateRecogniser = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRotate:)];
    _panRecogniser = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    _tapRecogniser = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    _doubleTapRecogniser = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    _longPressRecogniser = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];

    [_pinchRecogniser setDelegate:self];
    [_rotateRecogniser setDelegate:self];
    [_panRecogniser setDelegate:self];
    [_tapRecogniser setDelegate:self];
    [_doubleTapRecogniser setDelegate:self];
    [_longPressRecogniser setDelegate:self];

    [self addGestureRecognizer:_pinchRecogniser];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:_rotateRecogniser];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:_panRecogniser];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:_tapRecogniser];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:_doubleTapRecogniser];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:_longPressRecogniser];

    _tapRecogniser.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    _doubleTapRecogniser.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [_tapRecogniser requireGestureRecognizerToFail:_doubleTapRecogniser];

    [self setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
}

- (IBAction) handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)recogniser {
    recogniser.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recogniser.view.transform, recogniser.scale, recogniser.scale);
    recogniser.scale = 1;
}

- (IBAction) handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)recogniser {
    recogniser.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recogniser.view.transform, recogniser.rotation);
    recogniser.rotation = 0;
}

- (IBAction) handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recogniser {

}

- (IBAction) handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recogniser {
    [self reset:YES];
}

- (IBAction) handleLongPress:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recogniser {

}

- (IBAction) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recogniser {
    if (recogniser.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || recogniser.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [recogniser translationInView:self.superview];
        CGPoint translatedCenter = CGPointMake(self.center.x + translation.x, self.center.y + translation.y);
        [self setCenter:translatedCenter];
        [recogniser setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];
    }
}

- (void) reset:(BOOL)animation {
    if (!animation) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.center = self.superview.center;
    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            self.center = self.superview.center;
        }];
    }
}

- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
@end
```